# Accessing IIS from internal IPs

Tags: rewrite, iis, proxy, windows-8

I have a small webserver set up running Windows 8 Pro and IIS 8. One can access the site from the [external domain](http://www.thevgc.net/) easily enough, but accessing it internally becomes a chore given the fact that I want to have a rule set up to redirect `thevgc.net` to `www.thevgc.net`. My question is, how can I go about setting up some form of reverse proxy or internal DNS server to allow for other computers on the same LAN to access said web sever?

Comment: What happens when machines on the lan try to access the server?  I'm not understanding enough about what isn't working.

Comment: I can access the main site from the server's internal IP, but not from the domain I assigned to it. When I do, the browser loads indefinitely and then says that `"Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to thevgc.net"`

Comment: Setup an internal DNS entry that points that domain name to the internal IP.

Comment: How would I do that on Windows? I've only ever delved into that once, and that was on Ubuntu about a year-and-a-half ago.